# The class of an element is not reflected after append()

Tags: jquery, append

I have a function to add rows in a table, but after adding the class of a particular 'td' is not reflected.

```
$("#add_resource_button").click(function() {
    $("#add_resource_table").append('<tr><td><select name="add_resource"></select></td><td><select name="add_role"></select></td><td><input type="text" name="start_date_tentative" class="date"/></td></tr>');});
```

Here for the class"date" I have implemented the datepicker plugin, which is supposed to show the calender pop up for all the fields with class="date"......But for the 'td' that gets added after the button click this is not happening.

I tried using:

```
$("#add_resource_button").on ("click",".date",function() {
        $("#add_resource_table").append('<tr><td><select name="add_resource"></select></td><td><select name="add_role"></select></td><td><input type="text" name="start_date_tentative" class="date"/></td></tr>');
});
```

which is not adding the rows itself. Can anyone suggest a solution to get this done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you calling the datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#add_resource_button").click(function () {
    var $row = $('<tr><td><select name="add_resource"></select></td><td><select name="add_role"></select></td><td><input type="text" name="start_date_tentative" class="date"/></td></tr>').appendTo('#add_resource_table');
    $row.find('.row').datepicker();
});
```